# AWS OpenVPN instance can't ssh to other ec2 instances of connect to web

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openvpn

I set up an OpenVPN EC2 instance on AWS and it has security groups like

[image: openvpn security groups]

I downloaded the `client.ovpn` file and can successfully connect to it like `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn` in Ubuntu (and also via Network Manager after importing the config). All good.

Now I want to make it so my other EC2 instances (that host the actual app) can only be accessed via the VPN, and can't be SSH'd into directly for example. The security group of one of these EC2 instances looks like

[image]

where here I'm allowing inbound traffic on port 22 from the *Private IPv4 addresses* of the OVPN server.

However, if I connect to the VPN and try to SSH to the app EC2 instance it just times out, nor can I access the web when connected to the VPN.
If I allow SSH on port 22 from 0.0.0.0 then I can SSH in and no issues.

Could anyone point me toward what the problem might be?

Could it be because they are on different subnets?

Comment: What are the result you want to achieve?
If you want to let the current OpenVPN instance be the "bastion host" that will be the only point allowed to access to all other instances, then OpenVPN is not necessary

Comment: Well I want to achieve that I can only ssh into ec2 instances via the OpenVPN instance and also I have a jupyter notebook hosting instance and I want to only be able to connect to its public url when on the open vpn.

Comment: So
1/ you are trying to access the EC2 instances with their Public IPs?
2/ And these EC2 instances does not join the VPN
3/ You only join VPN with your current workstation
4/ You enabled SSH access for traffic that comes from "the private IP address of OpenVPN instance?"

Comment: 1/ I can access via SSH the app EC2s with their Public IPv4 DNS if the VPN is off and if I open the security group up to allow the world (0.0.0.0) 2/ if I lockdown port 22 to allow allow from the VPN instances private IP address then connect to the VPN on my linux desktop machine, I timeout when trying to SSH into the app EC2s 3/ I join the VPN from my desktop, but at this moment VPN connection is allowed from any IP so long as they have the creds. May tighten that later 4/ yes, infact during debugging I enabled all traffic from the private IP of the openv VPN instance just to rule things out

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution: [Forward all traffic through OpenVPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462533/route-all-traffic-through-openvpn). Restrict and connect to your instances with OpenVPN's **public IP**, connect to your EC2s through their **public IPs**

The reason why your solution did not work as I understand it

- AWS VPC is kind of like a VPN already
- You are trying to connect to your EC2 through their **public IP** which routes through the internet so it makes litte sense allowing OpenVPN's **private IP** as to talk with EC2's public IP the server that you are installing OpenVPN shall use their public IP
  [image]
- If you must use OpenVPN and does not want the internal (OpenVPN to EC2) connections to surface to the internet, the EC2 instances must join OpenVPN's private network, there, everyone can talk using the private IPs of OpenVPN's range
- Or [extend AWS VPC with OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/extending-vpn-connectivity-to-amazon-aws-vpc-using-aws-vpc-vpn-gateway-service/)
- Or see if [split-tunnel](https://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/02/21/access-local-and-vpn-network-simultaneously/) work which "[May allow users to access their LAN devices while connected to VPN](https://openvpn.net/for/split-tunneling-with-access-server/)"